# why can't amazon codebuild execute: docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml build?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, yaml, amazon-ecs

I am new to AWS.
I am trying to deploy a multi-container docker application with with CI/CD using CodePipeline and AWS ECR. I am using following this example: https://aws.plainenglish.io/deploy-multi-container-docker-to-elastic-beanstalk-with-ci-cd-using-codepipeline-and-aws-ecr-d1d5be0aaa20

CodeBuild is executing this command:
`docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml build` from the buildspec.yml

```
build:
    commands:
      # Test Build (Dockerfile.dev)
      #- echo Build started on `date`
      #- echo Building Docker test image...
      #- docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$TEST_IMAGE_TAG -f Dockerfile.dev .
      #- docker run -e CI=true $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$TEST_IMAGE_TAG npm run test
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml build
```

the error message is:

```
[Container] 2022/11/12 18:09:44 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml build. Reason: exit status 1
```

here is the docker-compose-prod.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  api: 
    build: 
      context: ./api
    container_name: api
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/app-api
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
  ui: 
    build: 
      context: ./ui
    container_name: ui
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/app-ui
    ports: 
      - "4200:4200"
  nginx: 
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on: 
      - ui
      - api
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/app-nginx
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
```

here is my private registies
[image]

why can't amazon execute this command?

also here is Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "ui",
      "image": "my_accnt_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-ui",
      "hostname": "ui",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 1024,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 4200,
          "containerPort": 4200
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "api",
      "image": "my_accnt_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-api",
      "hostname": "api",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 512,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3000,
          "containerPort": 3000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "my_accnt_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-nginx",
      "hostname": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": ["ui", "api"],
      "memory": 512
    }
  ]
}
```

my my_accnt_id is where i actually have my account id.

CloudWatch error msg:

```
2022-11-12T17:37:27.435+00:00

Copy
[Container] 2022/11/12 17:37:25 Running command docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push
[Container] 2022/11/12 17:37:25 Running command docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push

2022-11-12T17:37:27.435+00:00

Copy
Pushing api (280757731345.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-api:latest)...
Pushing api (280757731345.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-api:latest)...

2022-11-12T17:37:27.435+00:00

Copy
The push refers to repository [280757731345.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-api]
The push refers to repository [280757731345.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-api]

2022-11-12T17:38:18.717+00:00

Copy
EOF
EOF

2022-11-12T17:38:18.717+00:00

Copy


2022-11-12T17:38:18.717+00:00

Copy
[Container] 2022/11/12 17:38:16 Command did not exit successfully docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push exit status 1
[Container] 2022/11/12 17:38:16 Command did not exit successfully docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push exit status 1

2022-11-12T17:38:18.717+00:00   [Container] 2022/11/12 17:38:16 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED

2022-11-12T17:38:18.717+00:00

Copy
[Container] 2022/11/12 17:38:16 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2022/11/12 17:38:16 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push. Reason: exit status 1
```

I don't know why its failing to push.

Comment: There has to be more in the CodeBuild logs. There should be some output from the `docker-compose` command in the logs showing why it exited. Please check the CloudWatch Logs for the CodeBuild task.

Comment: @MarkB thats really all there is. now i am getting another msg that ive run out of my limit to push for Docker on top of the original msg.

Comment: You should try adding `--log-level DEBUG` to the `docker-compose` command.

Comment: i will try and get back to you, anything helps at this point